# If my account is deleted from a Stack Exchange site, will my username no longer be hyperlinked to my profile on questions I posted?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts

I just created a new account at Meta, and I might create others on the Stack Exchange network. I might post other questions, but if I decide to request an account deletion, will my username no longer be linked to the profile? I.e. will it just be text?

To me that would make sense, but I didn't want to assume.